# Please change the default sort order on the user page to display unanswerd questions first

Tags: feature-request, sorting

Now that accept rates are "all the rage"

Can you please change the default sort order for the questions (on the profile page) to display the questions with no accepted answers (excluding wiki) first.

That way:

1. It's easier to fix the problem
2. It advertises your non-answered questions much better.

At the bare minimum can you add a sort order for this on the profile page

Answer (score 1):

I believe Jeff's solution was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+hasaccepted:0+answers:1+wiki:0+closed:0), although this could be a nice addition.